# progress in a long running API? (Nodejs & express)

Tags: node.js, express

I have made an API which generates 3d Models. Sometimes this can take a long time (>5 min).
When it succeeds it returns the 3d Model in text form with statuscode 200. When failing I return the errorcode with statuscode 400.

Is there any way / mechanism to return a progress of processes? how could I do this? and how would Browsers read this?

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next logic for this:

1. Client doing request `/generateModel` to generate model;
2. Server returns `operation_id`;
3. Now client can do request `/getStatus` with gained `operation_id`;
4. Server will answer about progress and result: `{ status: 0, progress: 0.02 }`.
   Possible statuses:

- `0` - still generating with progress (`0.00`-`0.99`)(`{ status: 0, progress: 0.02 }`);
- `200` - done (`{ status: 1 }`);
- `other numbers` - error (`{ status: 500, message: "Internal error" }`);

5. Client asks server about status with some interval;
6. When client get response with `done` status, client requests model `/getModel`;
7. If client get response with `error` status, it will be displayed.